# WebPack: Uncaught ReferenceError: BrotliBitReader is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pdfmake

I am using WebPack to build a module (pdfmake) for the browser. The dependency chain includes a module called [brotli.js](https://github.com/devongovett/brotli.js) which is failing on the following line.

What I'm trying to figure out is why does it throw an exception when `BrotliBitReader` is clearly defined right above.

Here is a screenshot of the exception (where the breakpoint is):

[image]

Here is full stacktrace:

[image]

Here is my [WebPack config](https://gist.github.com/danawoodman/91b9e4dd727fd19c7dba021b05157dba)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add it to the global scope.

Try doing something like

```
window.BrotliBitReader = function(input) {
    etc...
}
```

I'm still trying to figure out how Webpack handles things as well, so let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If you need something that must exist outside of webpack's module scope, then you use [externals!!!](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals)

To quote our own docs:

> `externals` configuration in webpack provides a way of not including a dependency in the bundle. Instead the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumers environment. This typically applies to library developers though application developers can make good use of this feature too.